# Xcode: How do I get my UIView to stop scrolling and be locked in position?

Tags: xcode, uiview, tableview

So I have a tableViewController that contains a TableView which contains a CustomCell and a regular UIView.

The regular UIView is placed above where I want my table to be. The problem is that because a table is scrollable, every time I scroll up and down, the UIView scrolls with it.

is there any way to lock the UIView in position so that it doesn't move??

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Is the `UIView` a part of your custom cell? Are you doing this in `XIB` or via code?

Comment: The UIView is not part of the custom cell, it is part of the tableView. The tableView has my UIView and custom cell. In storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood, I think you want a `UIView` placed above a `tableView` at a fixed position.

As @Colin has mentioned in #1 of his answer, you can implement this using a `UIViewController` as root instead of using a `TableViewController`.
Just add a `UIView` and a `tableView` below it as required. Don't forget to connect the `tableView`'s `delegate` and `datasource` in `storyboard`. 

Also, confirm to the protocols

```
< UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate >
```

in your, `viewController`'s `.h` file.

Your `storyboard` should look somewhat like this:
[image]

The green colored `view` is your fixed positioned `view`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I literally just implemented exactly what you said and it works! thanks both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Three ways, none so fun:

1. refactor so there's a UIView that owns the UITableView, instead of having UITableView being the root - then add your locked UIView to the root - of course, then you either can't use UITableViewController, or have to use view controller containment.
2. In the table view's delegate's UIScrollViewDelegate::scrollViewDidScroll method, reposition your locked view.
3. Dunno if this'll work: try adding your locked view to the root UIWindow.

Comment: I have tried #3 before and it won't let you add a UIView to the root window since it's a tableViewController. I'm going to try your first suggestion. I'm guessing then I have to implement the data source and delegate protocols manually? Also I have several methods that implement [tableView reloadData] method right now. But if I switch the tableViewController to a UIViewController, Xcode will not recognize the tableView object anymore right?

Comment: You can switch the `tableViewController` to a `UIViewController`. you just have to confirm to the corresponding protocols, i.e. `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.